# How do I change the online status of an Azure SQL Database to offline

Tags: azure-sql-database

I want to change the status of my Azure SQL Database to offline, but cant see a way to do it from the management portal.

Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: What is your scenario for taking the database offline?

Comment: I kind of wanted to put it to sleep for a bit while I do some other stuff and didn't want to get billed for it :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a firewall setting to deny all the IP addresses, your won't get double billed and your database is intact. The other option is rename but I wouldn't go with it unless needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270017.aspx

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking to pause the Azure SQL Database to save money, now there is also a vCore-based purchase model for SQL databases in Azure.

After choosing vCore-based billing, you need to choose between:

- Provisioned: Compute resources are pre-allocated. Billed per hour based on vCores configured​.
  or
- Serverless: Compute resources are auto-scaled​. Billed per second based on vCores used​.

If you choose "Provisioned" you can enable "auto-pause" where the database automatically pauses if it is inactive for the time period specified (eg. 1 Hour or more), and automatically resumes when database activity recurs.

Source: https://portal.azure.com

Comment: While this is good information in general, it's hard to say if this explicitly answers the OP's questions since the vCore model doesn't seem to offer a way to force-pause the db.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to take a database "offline" without deleting the database. A few alternatives are deleting the database and then restoring it at a later day (7, 14, 35 days) depending on the edition of the database (basic, standard, premium) respectively or exporting the database to Azure storage and then restoring at a later date.

Comment: Thanks for you time here and just a footnote to your answer, I found out by accident that if I do a restore I get two databases, one has the original name and one has a date stamp appended to the database name.The objects that I created are not fully restored . The upshot is that my apps don't work any longer. Very Alarming !!. The fix is to open SS management studio and do a rename. Just a bit of info :-)

Answer (score 1):

For purpose of reducing the expenses you can downscale your database to `S0` tier, which allows for same 250Gb as `S3` and will cost just 15$ per month.

If you have a premium database with size more than 250Gb, than you can export it to a `.bacpac` and just delete / re-import. But this actually takes a lot of time and is hard to automate.

Denying all IP-s will not prevent billing AFAIK.